# SQLDriverConnect fails sometimes when enclosing the password in {}

Tags: oracle, winapi, ms-access, odbc

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for SQLDriverConnect,

> Because of connection string and initialization file grammar, keywords and attribute values that contain the characters []{}(),;?*=!@ not enclosed with braces should be avoided.

and

> A DSN or connection string value enclosed with braces ({}) containing any of the characters []{}(),;?*=!@ is passed intact to the driver.

Using the connection string `DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD={%s}` works in SQLServer - infact if there are certain special characters then not enclosing the password in {} fails. However, using the same string for MS Access fails with "invalid password" and works when `{}` is removed. It also does not work with Oracle.

If the string enclosed in the {} is passed intact to the server, then shouldn't it work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: On Linux Oracle does not pass across a @ symbol when using DG4ODBC to connect to ODBC. Not sure if that is the same on Windows but I too would love to find out how to do it if it is at all possible.

Comment: I don't know about Oracle, but Access has its own rules about special (or acceptable) characters and delimiters. Try with square-brackets [] rather than curly {}. But Access will not allow certain characters in the password - I haven't yet found what these are specifically.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLDriverConnect's Access-specific page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713896%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that:

> The PWD keyword should not include any of the special characters (see SQL_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS in SQLGetInfo Returned Values).

Calling the [SQLGetInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while connected to Access and passing SQL_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS as the InfoType argument should return the forbidden characters @Andrew Gibson mentioned.

The "More Information" section of a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826763) has a list of special characters not recommended for use in an Access app.

IBM's DB2 has an identically named [SQLGetInfo function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000615.html) with an identical parameter list and takes the same InfoType constant to return special characters, listed there as:

> all characters except a...z, A...Z, 0...9, and underscore